# object is passed to the `custom_objects` argument

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, model

I tried to load a model that is saved with a custom metric. So I should define custom metric and pass it to the `custom_objects` argument. I write the following codes:

```
## metric function
def coeff_determination(y_true, y_pred):
    SS_res =  K.sum(K.square( y_true-y_pred )) 
    SS_tot = K.sum(K.square( y_true - K.mean(y_true) ) ) 
    return ( 1 - SS_res/(SS_tot + K.epsilon()) )


## load models from file
def load_all_models(n_models,Cus_bjects):
    all_models = list()
    for i in range(n_models):
        # define filename for this ensemble
        filename = 'snapshot_model_' + str(i + 1) + '.h5'
        # load model from file
        model = load_model(filename,custom_objects=Cus_bjects)
        # add to list of members
        all_models.append(model)
        print('>loaded %s' % filename)
    return all_models

## load models in order
dependencies = {'metrics' : coeff_determination}
members = load_all_models(10,dependencies)
```

But I got the following error:

```
ValueError: Unknown metric function: coeff_determination. Please ensure this object is passed to the `custom_objects` argument. See https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize#registering_the_custom_object for details.
```

I have read `https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras...` but I can not realize what is wrong with these codes.

Comment: It should be dependencies = {'coeff_determination' : coeff_determination} and then pass this to custom_objects

Comment: Thank you. It woks.